# How to yaw with Oculus Rift

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, oculus

I'm currently working on Oculus where the player can control his character only with head tracking. The character is a bird flying in 3D. Testing the gameplay, it was alright, but i almost killed myself with the Oculus wire when i was trying to yaw. So, i decided to make it easier for the player. I would like to allow player yawing when he is looking at his right/left anywhere in the space (kind of free roam) and make the gameobject + camera rotate with him.

I tried to use slerp, but it was not really effective.

```
transform.position = transform.position + cameraRight.transform.forward * distance * Time.deltaTime;


transform.Rotate(Vector3.Cross(transform.forward, cameraRight.transform.forward), distance * Time.deltaTime);
```

These is the code i use to make my bird move forward and make the camera rotate. But now, i would like to limit player to 45° left and right, and once he look in a direction, the bird yaw automatically.

I don't know if it's clear, but it's like when driving a car, you don't have to move all the steering wheel to go left/right, you just have to rotate and the wheels are following.

Comment: I'm just trying to get this straight. So, you want it to be normal oculus control, except that when they turn their head past 45 degrees, they only need to hold their head there while it rotates automatically (kind of like putting your mouse to the edge in an RTS game)?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what i'm thinking about